# fixing chromosome with new contig

Tags: assembly, chromosomes

I want to fix a chromosome of around 50-100Mb (`chr.fasta`) for a region that is missing a few kilobases of data. I have the missing sequence with a window upstream and downstream that matches perfectly to the reference (`contig.fasta`).

What's the best way to produce a new chromosome, `fixed.fasta` that contains the new data from `contig.fasta`?

See depiction below:

```
chr.fasta    |---------------------------------------------------   -------------|
contig.fasta                                                   |-===-|
```

Final intended result:

```
fixed.fasta  |---------------------------------------------------===-------------|
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have not received any answer to the question, so I created a small tool to fix the file myself.

I am assuming as per the question that there are perfect matches upstream and downstream to the new sequence, and that anything in between can be deleted/updated by the new sequence.

Given the first_n and last_n bases of the diagram in the question, and the entire patch sequence, we can create a single-line string of the reference with `seqtk seq -l9999999 -` and then edit it with the line below (in Perl regex):

```
$chromosome_str =~ s/$first_n.+$last_n/$patch/i
```

This creates the new string that can be used as the new fasta file.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try with `megamerger` from the `emboss` suite if you have (almost) perfect sequence match.

In case the gap within your `chr.fasta` complicates the sequence alignment and hence the resulting contig, you can generate a "tiling path" with: upstream of the gap from `chr.fasta` + `contig.fasta` + downstream of the gap from `chr.fasta` (there should be sequence overlaps of course)

In a (more realistic) scenario where there is no perfect sequence match between the overlapping regions, you can fall back to `emboss merger`, however, it is not designed to work on large sequences.